# How to force ReSharper to keep/add a using static directive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

How can I force ReSharper in Visual Studio to add a static alias directive automatically, or, at least, prevent it from removing it upon cleaning usings when it is unused?

For example:

```cs
using static Facade;
```

If no piece of code references members from `Facade`, ReSharper will mark it for removal upon cleaning. However, unlike namespaces, which I can force to keep/add in `ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Namespace Imports`, I don't see a way to keep the `using static` directive regardless of its usage.

Comment: Have you already checked the [JetBrains ReSharper support site](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us)?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes, unfortunately I found nothing related in their knowledge base and on Google.